What memory consistency is appropriate for a std::coroutine_handle<> passed between threads?
I have a situation in which a "callee" thread is spinning on a std::atomic<coroutine_handle<>>, and resumes it as soon as the handle is not null.  A separate "caller" thread then writes a non-NULL std::coroutine_handle<> there.  The situation looks roughly like this:
  std::atomic<std::coroutine_handle<>> caller = nullptr;

  // In caller coroutine
  void await_suspend(std::coroutine_handle<> h) {
    caller.store(h, std::memory_order_???);   // <- line 1
  }

  // In callee coroutine
  struct TailCoro {
    std::coroutine_handle<> jump_back_to_;
    bool await_ready() const noexcept { return false; }
    auto await_suspend(std::coroutine_handle<>) const noexcept
    {
      return jump_back_to_;
    }
    void await_resume() const noexcept { std::terminate(); }
  };
  TailCoro final_suspend() noexcept {
    for (;;)
      if (std::coroutine_handle<> h =
          caller.load(std::memory_order_???)) // <- line 2
        return TailCoro{.jump_back_to_ = h};
  }

My question: what are the correct memory orderings to use in the two places with ????
A priori, I would think that the caller (line 1) might need to use release semantics and the callee (line 2) acquire semantics, since coroutine state will migrate between threads.  However, since all that state should be accessed through the coroutine_handle<>, maybe consume semantics are sufficient.
On the other hand, cppreference.com states:

Note that because the coroutine is fully suspended before entering awaiter.await_suspend(), that function is free to transfer the coroutine handle across threads, with no additional synchronization.

So maybe line 1 doesn't need to synchronize with line 2 at all in the above code, and std::memory_order_relaxed is okay in both places, because internally the suspend and resume operations contain the equivalent of release and acquire fences.

The appropriate memory consistency for this scenario is to use std::memory_order_release when the caller writes to the atomic handle and std::memory_order_acquire when the callee reads it. This ensures proper synchronization and visibility of memory changes between the two threads.

So you are saying the point about synchronization being unnecessary on cppreference.com isn't accurate?  Also, can you elaborate as to why std::memory_order_consume is not sufficient in the callee (line 2)?  What's the scenario in which coroutine state updates preceding a release store in line 1 would not be dependency ordered before access to that coroutine state through the coroutine handle returned from line 2?

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
